# Printing at timed intervals

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, time

I know how to utilize `time.sleep()`, but I was curious how to print something like so:

```
"hey...(pause)...you...(pause)....there"
```

where the 'pause' is some `time.sleep()` interval. I can only print these intervals on separate lines. Is there a way to keep it all on one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python 2:

```
print "hey...",
time.sleep(0.5)
```

In python 3:

```
print("hey...", end=' ')
time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Does this keep it all on the same line?

Comment: Ah, the trailing comma. That's the key. Thanks!

Comment: If this answer helped you, please consider accpeting it.

Answer (score 1):

In a `print` statement in python2.x, you can suppress the newline with a trailing comma:

```
 print "hey...",
 time.sleep(1)
 print "...you...",
 time.sleep(1)
 print "....there"
```

On python3.x (or with `from __future__ import print_function` enabled), you use the `end` keyword to the `print` *function*:

```
 print("hey...", end="")
```

etc.

---

Or, finally, you can always<sup>1</sup> write to the `sys.stdout` stream:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("hey...")
time.sleep(1)
...
```

The advantage here is that you can flush it explicitly:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>technically not always.  `sys.stdout` *could* be replaced by something else:  `sys.stdout = 3` -- But making a mess without cleaning up after yourself is terribly rude.  However, if you ever find yourself in that situation, `sys.__stdout__` is a backup ;-).</sup>

Comment: Oh, its on! Battle of the `print` statements :P

Comment: Uh - uh.  Oh No you di-ent!  Don't you even think about bringin' that `sys.stdout.write` in here!

Comment: hey! won't this have issues with flushing?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget -- good question.  I'm not sure if `print` flushes or not.  Of course, if it does, you could always run with `python -u` and then my answer is still correct ;-)

Comment: True. But I would go with `sys.out.write` if flushing doesn't happen